# Importing custom Mesh (DAE) fails due to Buffer Out of Memory

Tags: gazebo-world, collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello All,
I am trying to create an environment model with a custom COLLADA DAE. The file is around 100MB size. However, Gazebo is unable to import the DAE and gives me this error:
Error [Visual.cc:1668] Unable to insert mesh[Vertex Buffer: Out of memory

I am not sure if it is a Gazebo or OGRE issue. Any suggestions on how to fix this?
Thanks
Ammar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/143/importing-custom-mesh-(dae)-fails-due-to-buffer-out-of-memory/) by [ammar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/75/ammar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-11-06**:
Can you post the collada file online so that I can download it?

**Comment by [ammar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/75/ammar/) on 2012-11-06**:
Sure. They are at gs6144.sp.cs.cmu.edu/share/Ammar/    The one I was trying was Ground.dae. Thanks!

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-07-24**:
think I might have seen errors like this before on an old quadro fx 1600m (256MB memory), might be a gpu issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We have verified that this mesh loads using gazebo 1.9 on a laptop, though gazebo is rather slow. Is this still a problem for you? What version of gazebo are you using?

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1096/dmngu9/) on 2015-02-07**:
i have the same problem atm. please let me know if you got it working